# Como agregar nuevo campo en colección de mongodb mediante un updateMany con node.js

Tags: mongodb, update

Estoy tratando de agregar un nuevo campo a todos los documentos de una colección usando updateMany de la siguiente forma:

```
clearUser: async(req,res)=>{
        try {
            await client.connect()
            const cleared= await client.db("wkkpark").collection("users").updateMany({},
            {$set:{isCleared:true}}) //este campo no existe previamente.
            console.log(cleared)
            res.send(cleared)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        finally{
            client.close()
        }
        
    }
```

Desafortunadamente, obtengo el siguiente resultado.

```
 "acknowledged": true,
    "modifiedCount": 0,
    "upsertedId": null,
    "upsertedCount": 0,
    "matchedCount": 0
```

No veo que estoy haciendo mal en mi sintaxis. Agradecería si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Comment: si ensayas un find `const result = await client.db("wkkpark").collection("users").find()` si te encuentra resultados? Porque a simple vista no veo nada raro en el updateMany, el error no está en como accedes a la base de datos o a la referencia de la coleccion?